# Loop through a collection of objects n at a time

Tags: loops, powershell, powercli

I am a self-taught, newbie programmer, and I feel like this is a really basic question, the kind I'd be able to answer if I had actually studied computer science :P In my searching of the intertrons and StackOverflow I haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for. So I hope someone can indulge me.

I have a collection of objects. I want to operate on them five at a time, and then move on to the next five. The context is rebooting a bunch of VMs; I'm being asked to stagger them so that the hosts aren't slammed with all of the VMs rebooting at once.

I sense that the right path is a `for i` loop in some capacity, and not `foreach`. I also feel like it could be a combination of `do-until` and `for i` but I can't sift the answer out of my brain.

I could probably do it by removing objects from the collection, but that feels like the "wrong" way to do this, even if it would work.

I'm doing this with Powershell and PowerCLI, but I feel as though the logic I'm trying to understand is more basic than being dependent on any language, so even if you're not familiar with Powershell, I'm interested in your answer.

Edit: Based on David's answer below, the following code seems to be what I'm looking for:

```
$someLetters = @("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k")

for($i=0; $i -lt $someLetters.length; $i+=5)
{
    Write-Host ("the letter is " + $someLetters[$i] + " and i is " + $i)
    Write-Host ("the letter is " + $someLetters[$i+1] + " and i is " + $i)
    Write-Host ("the letter is " + $someLetters[$i+2] + " and i is " + $i)
    Write-Host ("the letter is " + $someLetters[$i+3] + " and i is " + $i)
    Write-Host ("the letter is " + $someLetters[$i+4] + " and i is " + $i)
    write-host "finished block of five"
}
```

gives the output:

```
the letter is a and i is 0
the letter is b and i is 0
the letter is c and i is 0
the letter is d and i is 0
the letter is e and i is 0
finished block of five
the letter is f and i is 5
the letter is g and i is 5
the letter is h and i is 5
the letter is i and i is 5
the letter is j and i is 5
finished block of five
the letter is k and i is 10
the letter is  and i is 10
the letter is  and i is 10
the letter is  and i is 10
the letter is  and i is 10
finished block of five
```

Thank you David!

Comment: Interesting question. I'll have some fun with this.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm still experimenting, and I feel like the answer is right on the tip of my brain. So frustrating, but simultaneously what I love about programming.

Comment: On an unrelated note, note that double quotes replace variables with their values. So `"i = $i" would write `i = 0` and `'i = $i` would literally write `i = $i`.

Comment: and you can use `$()` to evaluate an expression, so you could do this: `$i..($i+5) | Foreach { "The letter is $($someLetters[$i]) and $$i is $i" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what kind of container your objects are in.  I'll assume it's an array.  So, you could do something like this:

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $objectArray.length; $i+=5)
{
    #do something with $objectArray[$i]
}
```

Comment: Probably better than what I was trying. I was splitting the array into an array of arrays of 5 objects. I was having trouble with it.

Comment: Yeah, it's an array. I think this is the right path. I wanted to understand your logic, so I did this test:

`$someLetters = @("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k")`

`for($i=0; $i -lt $someLetters.length; $i+=5)`
`{`
` Write-Host ("the letter is " + $someLetters[$i] + " and i is " + $i)`
`}`

Which gives the output:

`the letter is a and i is 0`
`the letter is f and i is 5`
`the letter is k and i is 10`

But if I add four more lines that do the same operation with `$i+1`, `$i+2`, etc, I get all the letters! Thank you :-)

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I hadn't tried to do code in a comment before.

Comment: @Formica I wasn't sure I understood what you meant by "operate on them five at a time".  I took that to mean every 5th object.  That's why the loop uses "i+=5".  If you meant something else, perhaps you could clarify, then I could adjust the solution.  On the other hand, if you're happy as is, then I'm glad I could help.  Cheers!

Comment: I assumed it would be `#do something with $objectArray[$i..$i+5]`, so you're spot on!